# How to use the cordova file plugin in browser?

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, ionic-framework

I am using the [cordova file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) on my iPod and its working without any issues. Now I would like to run the same app in my chrome browser and use it there as well. Here is the code that I am trying to execute:

```
fileFactory.doesConfigurationExist = function ()
    {
        var q = $q.defer();
        $cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, configurationFile).then(function (success)
            {
                q.resolve(success);
            },
            function (error)
            {
                q.reject(error);
            });
        return q.promise;
    };
```

Unfortunately I get the following error and the function goes into the reject:

5 ENCODING_ERR

The documentation doesn't say a lot about this error. I am running my ionic applications as:

```
cordova run browser
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: There are just a few plugins which you can use with browser as a platform. Browser as a platform is not for building web apps, it's just for function tests.

Comment: I understand. I am trying to test the UI which is dependent on the data. I guess I will have to pre-populate the data somehow and test it out. Pain in the ass, but it is what it is.

Comment: If forgotten the name, but there is a plugin for developing. This plugin injects JS / HTML immediately to your device.

Comment: Oh. Let me google it. If you remember the name, please post it here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 file APIs will work in the browser just fine. In fact the file plugin references it as documentation.  The file plugin is supported in the browser.  Read the documentation here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

What you may need to do is handle platform specific directories correctly.  Use the device plugin to figure out what platform you are running on and adjust from there.

Also note there is a "QUIRK" for Chrome and the file plugin.  You have to wait for an additional event after device ready to safely use the plugin:

```
window.addEventListener('filePluginIsReady', function(){ console.log('File plugin is ready');}, false);
```

Oh, Chrome also has extra security you need to override otherwise it won't work:

```
Chrome requires --allow-file-access-from-files run argument to support API via file:/// protocol.
```

It's all there in the documentation.

Answer (score -4):

You can't

> Cordova plugins do not work while developing in your browser, because
>   each plugin accesses a specific API (such as camera, microphone,
>   accelerometer) which is not available in your browser. Additionally,
>   some plugins don't work in the emulator, such as the Camera plugin, so
>   development on your physical device is required.

http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/

Comment: Plenty of plugins work in the browser and File is one of them.  Just look in the plugin documentation to see what they support (i.e. they will say "browser").

That documentation at ngCordova has several errors in it.  With the new emulators / simulators more plugins than not with them.